# Socket send concurrency guarantees

Tags: linux, sockets

If I have a single socket shared between two processes (or two threads), and in both of them I try to send a big message (bigger than the underlining protocol buffer) that blocks, is it guaranteed that both messages will be sent sequentially? Or it possible for the messages to be interleaved inside the kernel?

I am mainly interested in TCP over IP behavior, but it would be interesting to know if it varies according to socket's protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking that if you `write()` message A, then B on the same socket, is A guaranteed to arrive before B?  For SOCK_STREAM (e.g. TCP) and SOCK_SEQPACKET (almost never used) sockets, the answer is an unqualified yes.  For SOCK_DGRAM over the internet (i.e. UDP packets) the answer is no: packets can be reordered by the network.  On a single host, a unix domain datagram socket will (on all systems I know) preserve ordering, but I don't believe that's guaranteed by any standard and I'm sure there are edge cases.

Or wait: maybe you're asking if the messages written by the two processes won't be mixed?  Yes: single system calls (write/writev/sendto/sendmsg) always place their content into a file descriptor atomically.  But obviously if you or your library splits that write into multiple calls, you lose that guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

For UDP, if two threads write to a socket handle simultaneously, both messages will be sent as separate datagrams. Might undergo IP fragmentation if the packet is larger than MTU, but resulting datagrams will be preserved and reassembled correctly by the receiver.  In other words, you are safe for UDP, except for the normal issues associated with UDP (datagram reordering, packet loss, etc...).

For TCP, which is stream based, I don't know.  Your question is essentially asking the equivalent of "if two threads try to write to the same file handle, will the file still be legible?"  I actually don't know the answer.

The simplest thing you can do is just use a thread safe lock (mutex) to guard send/write calls to the socket so that only on thread can write to the socket at a time.

For TCP, I would suggest having a dedicated thread for handling all socket io. Then just invent a way in which messages from the worker thrads can get asynchronously queued to the socket thread for it to send on.  The socket thread could also handle recv() calls and notify the other threads when the socket connection is terminated by the remote side.

Comment: I am writing to the socket from 2 different processes, and you got to my problem: avoid passing the messages between processes (as would be needed if I had a single writing process), when it is much preferable to just send them through the socket. I could sync the write with a semaphore, but I prefer to avoid the hassle if the kernel would do it anyway (that is the point of my question).

Comment: I came across this answer while trying to find out if sendto() over UDP is threadsafe. So that is the case? If so, great!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to send a large message on a STREAM socket that exceeds the underlying buffer size, it's pretty much guaranteed that you you will get a short write -- the write or send call will write only part of the data (as much as will fit in the buffer) and then return the amount written, leaving you to do another write for the remaining data.

If you do this in multiple threads or processes, then each write (or send) will thus write a small portion of the message atomically into the send buffer, but the subsequent writes might happen in any order, with the result that the large buffers being sent will get interleaved.

If you send messages on DGRAM sockets, on the other hand, either the entire message will be sent atomically (as a single layer 4 packet, which might be fragmented and reassembled by lower layers of the protocol stack), or you will get an error (`EMSGSIZE` linux or other UNIX variants)

Comment: what if we use MSG_WAITALL flag to write the large message ?  Is this guaranteed to be atomic ?